# My file is misconfigured for not being compressed

Tags: html, compression

I have a template and the pages of this were coming compressed, all code in one line. If I decompress a page for example with tool tabifier(tools.arantius.com/tabifier) and upload to the server clean html code, everything is fine in Chrome but in Mozilla and Explorer all appears misconfigured.

A) unzipped my page: http://capsularicaldone.com/index.php

B) the original compressed page: http://capsularicaldone.com/component_gallery.html

In A) only runs fine in Chrome and B) runs well on all browses
I have not changed a line of code, I just unzipped page

Comment: http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fcapsularicaldone.com%2Findex.php&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you should decompress all the pages in the template before uploading. Then, you should upload the decompressed pages.

Once you have done that, run your code through a validator:

http://validator.w3.org/